# Why does the SqlServer optimizer get so confused with parameters?

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization

I know this has something to do with parameter sniffing, but I'm just perplexed at how something like the following example is even possible with a piece of technology that does so many complex things well.

Many of us have run into stored procedures that intermittently run several of orders of magnitude slower than usual, and then if you copy out the sql from the procedure and use the same parameter values in a separate query window, it runs as fast as usual.

I just fixed a procedure like that by converting this:

```
alter procedure p_MyProc
(
    @param1 int
) as -- do a complex query with @param1
```

to this:

```
alter procedure p_MyProc
(
    @param1 int
)
as

declare @param1Copy int;
set @param1Copy = @param1;

-- Do the query using @param1Copy
```

It went from running in over a minute back down to under one second, like it usually runs.  This behavior seems totally random.  For 9 out of 10 @param1 inputs, the query is fast, regardless of how much data it ends up needing to crunch, or how big the result set it.  But for that 1 out of 10, it just gets lost.  And the fix is to replace an int with the same int in the query?

It makes no sense.

[Edit]

@gbn linked to this question, which details a similar problem:

[Known issue?: SQL Server 2005 stored procedure fails to complete with a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379007/known-issue-sql-server-2005-stored-procedure-fails-to-complete-with-a-parameter)

I hesitate to cry "Bug!" because that's so often a cop-out, but this really does seem like a bug to me.  When I run the two versions of my stored procedure with the same input, I see identical query plans.  The only difference is that the original takes more than a minute to run, and the version with the goofy parameter copying runs instantly.

Comment: Is it always the same value that makes it go slow? is there anything else going on in the database at the same time? what version of sql server are you running (latest service pack?)

Comment: Sql Server 2005, 9.00.3073.00.  The parameter in this case is the PK of a list table, with the query analyzing the items in the list in a different table.  I can repro it with roughly 1 in 10 list ids, regardless of activity on the db.  Query plans when running the two versions are identical.

Comment: Does the execution differ in those cases? I know the plan is the same, but what does sql profiler say the duration, read and write count is for each statement in the proc?

Comment: Right - SET STATISTICS IO and SET STATISTICS TIME. You know it's whacked if the statistics are the same.

Comment: It's not calling any sub-SPs is it? These can be problematic for sure.

Comment: Well, my users had the audacity to change the data, so my repros are gone.  I'm thinking it's less than 1/10 because I've been through about 100 now and can't find any more to get stats on.  Argh!  DBA work can be so. much. fun.

Answer (score 5):

The 1 in 10 gives the wrong plan that is cached.

RECOMPILE adds an overhead, masking allows each parameter to be evaluated on it's own merits (very simply).

By wrong plan, what if the 1 in 10 generates an scan on index 1 but the other 9 produce a seek on index 2? eg, the 1 in 10 is, say, 50% of the rows?

Edit: other questions

- [Known issue?: SQL Server 2005 stored procedure fails to complete with a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379007/known-issue-sql-server-2005-stored-procedure-fails-to-complete-with-a-parameter)
- [Stored Procedure failing on a specific user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272726/stored-procedure-failing-on-a-specific-user)

Edit 2:

Recompile does not work because the parameters are sniffed at compile time.
From other links (pasted in):

This [article](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/sql/2005/recomp.mspx#E6TAE) explains...

```
...parameter values are sniffed during compilation or recompilation...
```

Finally (edit 3):

Parameter sniffing was probably a good idea at the time and probably works well mostly. We use it across the board for any parameter that will end up in a WHERE clause.
We don't need to use it because we know that only a few (more complex eg reports or many parameters) could cause issues but we use it for consistency.

And the fact that it will come back and bite us when the users complain and we should have used masking...

Comment: It's difficult to tell because when this happens, I have noticed that the execution times are just wrong when the query finally completes.  The graphical plans look the same, but I don't trust them in this case.

Comment: I have confirmed that the plans are shown as the same and it's all seeks.

Comment: Thanks for the links @gbn.  The first one makes me think this is actually a bug, rather than some obscure expected parameter sniffing behavior.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably caused by the fact that SQL Server compiles stored procedures and **caches** execution plans for them and the cached execution plan is probably unsuitable for this new set of parameters. You can try `WITH RECOMPILE` option to see if it's the cause.

```
EXECUTE MyProcedure [parameters] WITH RECOMPILE
```

`WITH RECOMPILE` option will force SQL Server to ignore the cached plan.

Comment: The ALTER PROCEDURE caused the proc to recompile. You could have just run that or DROP/CREATE and fixed the problem.

Comment: The WITH RECOMPILE means that it will recompile in the future every time it's run, so you don't have to wait for it to get slow and then run an ALTER or DROP and CREATE.

Comment: No, with recompile had no effect.  That was the first thing I tried.

Comment: I have two procs, identical except for the parameter copying.  I run them both with the same inputs and see the same plan, just a big difference in execution time.  And I run them multiple times back and forth to rule out caching issues.

Answer (score 2):

I have had this problem repeatedly on moving my code from a test server to production - [on two different builds of SQL Server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379007/known-issue-sql-server-2005-stored-procedure-fails-to-complete-with-a-parameter).  I think there are some big problems with the parameter sniffing in some builds of SQL Server 2005.  I never had this problem on the dev server, or on two local developer edition boxes.  I've never seen it it be such a big problem on SQL Server 2000 or any version going back to 6.5 either.

The cases where I found it, the only workaround was to use parameter masking, and I'm still hoping the DBAs will patch up the production server to SP3 so it will maybe go away.  Things which did not work:

- using the WITH RECOMPILE hint on EXEC or in the SP itself.
- dropping and recreating the SP
- using sp_recompile

Note that in the case I was working on, the data was not changing since an earlier invocation - I had simply scripted the code onto the production box which already had data loaded.  All the invocations came with no changes to the data since before the SPs existed.

Oh, and if SQL Server can't handle this without masking, they need to add a parameter modifier NOSNIFF or something.  What happens if you mask all your parameters, so you have @Something_parm and @Something_var and someone changes the code to use the wrong one and all of a sudden you have a sniffing problem again?  Plus you are polluting the namespace within the SP.  All these SPs I am "fixing" drive me nuts because I know they are going to be a maintenance nightmare for the less experienced satff I will be handing this project off to one day.

Comment: Yeah, I have read that some people always mask every parameter in every proc.  Yikes, what a pain.  This is definitely a bug.  I'm on 9.00.3073.00, which I'm pretty sure is the latest update.

Answer (score 1):

Could you check on the SQL Profiler how many reads and execution time when it is quick and when it is slow? It could be related to the number of rows fetched depending on the parameter value. It doesn't sound like a cache plan issue.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a 2 year old thread, but it might help someone down the line.

Once you analyze the query execution plans and know what the difference is between the two plans (query by itself and query executing in the stored procedure with a flawed plan), you can modify the query within the stored procedure with a query hint to resolve the issue. This works in a scenario where the query is using the incorrect index when executed in the stored procedure. You would add the following after the table in the appropriate location of your procedure:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM YourTableHere WITH (INDEX (PK_YourIndexHere))
```

This will force the query plan to use the correct index which should resolve the issue. This does not answer why it happens but it does provide a means to resolve the issue without worrying about copying the parameters to avoid parameter sniffing.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated it be a compilation issue. Does this issue still occur if you revert the procedure? One thing you can try if this occurs again to force a recompilation is to use:

sp_recompile [ @objname = ] 'object'

Right from BOL in regards to @objname parameter:

Is the qualified or unqualified name of a stored procedure, trigger, table, or view in the current database. object is nvarchar(776), with no default. If object is the name of a stored procedure or trigger, the stored procedure or trigger will be recompiled the next time that it is run. If object is the name of a table or view, all the stored procedures that reference the table or view will be recompiled the next time they are run.

If you drop and recreate the procedure you could cause clients to fail if they try and execute the procedure. You will also need to reapply security settings.

Comment: No, recompiling had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any chance that the parameter value being provided is sometimes not int?

Comment: No.  I can repro it with specific ints.

Answer (score 0):

It is a problem with plan caching, and it isn't always related to parameters, as it was in your scenario.

(Parameter Sniffing problems occur when a proc is called with unusual parameters the FIRST time it runs, and so the cached plan works great for those odd values, but lousy for most other times the proc is called.)

We had a similar situation when the app team deleted all old records from a highly-used log table on a production server. Removing records improves performance, right? Nope, performance immediately tanked.

Turns out that a frequently-used stored proc was recompiled right when the table was nearly empty, and it cached an extremely poor execution plan ("hey, there's only 50 records here, might as well do a Table Scan!"). Would have happened no matter what the initial parameters.

Our fix was to force a recompile with sp_recompile.

Answer (score 0):

Is every query reference to the parameter comparing it with int values, without functions and without casting?

Can you increase the specificity of any expressions using the parameter to make the use of multifield indexes more likely?

Comment: No functions, no casting.  My two versions of the proc run with identical query plans, but the original hangs for a minute.

Comment: I've seen this kind of thing often enough. Just about every time, though, there's a "Doh!" moment when I finally figure out what I was doing wrong.